# Reheating a cooked meat pie

Tags: reheating

What is the best way to reheat a meat pie without causing the pastry to burn and go hard?

Wrapping in foil means it won't cook properly. Is it best to put inside a glass pie dish with a lid on?

Comment: Welcome to the site @David. Your question is not clear, do you want to reheat a cooked meat pie, or cook it from raw? You're either reheating it or cooking it, which is it?

Comment: What do you mean about the foil? A tinfoil hat would slow down the reheating of the bits most likely to burn while not steaming it (unlike the closed dish)